# How to disable Fujifilm Finepix S8XXX series zoom sound

Tags: zoom, sound

I notice that Fujifilm Finepix S8XXX series have very noisy zoom sound. This can be heard when recording a video and optical-zooming at the same time. Please refer to this video to know more about this zoom sound (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JVDx4aEb7TE)

Also, this zoom sound can also be heard in the Fujifilm Finepix S9XXX series. Please refer to this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u4bKP3fvdvY)

How do I disable this zoom sound when I am recording a video and optical-zooming at the same time? Is there a option that I can turn off or remove this zoom sound?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really mean "disable", with the implication that the sound is added on purpose and could be turned off?

Comment: I suspect that the sound is not added on purpose as other videos related to the Fujifilm Finepix S8XXX series and S9XXX series do have the zooming sound when the camera is optical-zooming in the video mode. I do not know if there is an option to turn off that zooming sound.

Answer (score 5):

The sound is not artificially added. (Why would they do that?) The act of zooming is powered by a motor, and the motor, by its nature, makes noise. You can't have the functionality of the motor without the sound. Therefore, you can't "disable" it.

Crude analogy: I'd like a quieter lawn mower. Can I turn off the sound of my lawn mower?